# CPU throttling all the time in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, cpu

I have Acer Aspire E5-511 running Dual-boot windows 10 alongwith Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I boot the system with Ubuntu, even if the temperature is below 50 degrees Celsius, the fan suddenly starts its speed to maximum and the screen and everything gets freezed and I have to pull out the battery to re-start the laptop. I think this is what we call as thermal throttling. This happens anytime and without any cause which I am unable to understand why this is happening. In windows 10, everything runs fine without any problem. I have to loose all my work if the processor starts throttling in anytime.

I have tried everything:-

1. Disabled intel_pstate driver
2. Uninstalled thermald
3. Changed the scaling_governer to performance
4. Added "acpi_osi=Linux" to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" in /etc/default/grub

But when I add acpi=off (instead of acpi_osi=Linux), I experienced much better but in that case, my wifi stops working and battery icon vanishses away.

So any help will be deeply appreciated.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please, reply fast. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/587408/cpu-always-throttled-fan-clicking and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205269/1910-cpu-always-throttled suggest you have a failed CPU fan.

Comment: No, my fan is working fine and no throttling in windows. Also, throttling occurs just only at 47 degree celsius.